# How to remove a ConnectionString using Config Transformations

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-config, web-config-transform

I have a Web.config with several ConnectionStrings

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connStr1" connectionString="...
    <add name="ConnStr2" connectionString="...
    <add name="connStr3" connectionString="...
```

Is there a way using config transformations to remove a specific connectionstring? Something Like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <xdt:Remove connStr2?
```

Obviously no where near the correct syntax, but you get my drift...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) on the subject:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="...">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="Remove" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The `Transform="Remove"` is the magic you're looking for. There is also a `Transform="RemoveAll"` which you might be able to use in conjunction with a specific add(s).

**EDIT**

On second thought you may also be able to combine the [`Locator` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd465326.aspx) with the `Remove` defined above to limit which elements you actually want to delete.

More definitively:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="...">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/connectionStrings[@name='ConnStr2'])" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Or similar should work.

Comment: The XPath won't work. The correct syntax is the one mentioned by @hyke20 bellow. To test the transformation online you can use: http://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/

Comment: Why would you remove the actual namespace in the sample above? It is: xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform". Fully:  [<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">]

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett Doing so limits the environment portability of the code which is the reason config transforms are used to begin with. There may be a way to do it but I'd suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 124):

This will remove a specific connection string based on its name.

```xml
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="ConnStr2" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" connectionString=" " /> 
  </connectionStrings> 
</configuration>
```

Note that the `connectionString` value is not empty string, but is instead a space. Any non-empty value would do.

Comment: The 'DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String' argument cannot be null or empty. Is what I get when I place your code inside my web.release.config. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why is the `connectionString` attribute required, at all? Shouldn't `xdt:Transform="Remove"` be able to remove the node based on its name only?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko & Leigh - I don't get that error when I use hyke20's example, but if I leave off the 'connectionString' property I get a warning that it's missing.

Comment: You may get a warning if the attribute is not present, but the transformation should still apply correctly. I personally use `connectionString="any"` to be clear to future me that the transform doesn't care what the value of the connection string is.