# Remove ASMX documentation in web.config transform

Tags: asp.net, asmx, web.config-transform

I'm able to successfully remove the ASMX WSDL help generator by adding this to my web.config

```
  <webServices>
      <protocols>
          <remove name="Documentation"/>
      </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

I'm also able to do some basic transformations to my config files as I publish to my debug and release configs doing things like this:

```
    <add key="UseEncrypted" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" value="true"/>
```

I'm having trouble however getting a combination of these two to work.  For example, I'd like to have my debug config to *not* have the `<remove>` tag, but my release *should* include the `<remove>` documentation tag.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible, and if so - can you please give some guidance?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920451/how-to-remove-a-connectionstring-using-config-transformations) for a similar example with connection strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue was to add `xdt:Transform="Remove"` to the protocols section.

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols xdt:Transform="Remove">
            <remove name="Documentation"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```